# Rails does not navigate to controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a new controller method. I also created a corresponding view for the same. All I am trying to do is create a variable called @x and printing it in the view. I am doing this just to verify if my application is going into the method. However, I do not see the value getting printed on the view. Please help.

This is my controller named submitted_content_controller.rb

```
class SubmittedContentController < ApplicationController

 def begin_planning
  @x = 1
 end
end
```

This is my view called begin_planning.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:action => :revision_planning), method: "post" %>
<%= text_field 'questionnaire', 'name', class: "form-control width-250" %>
<p><%= @x %></p>
<button>Create</button>
```

This is the routes I added:

```
get :begin_planning
```

When I am in the begin_planning html page, I see the text field and create button but I don't see the value of @x getting printed. It will be a huge help. Thank you.

This is my routes output:

```
begin_planning_submitted_content_index GET  /submitted_content/begin_planning(.:format)                   submitted_content_controller#begin_planning
```

there are other routes to which I didn't add, because this controller has many other methods which I did not add since it's a huge file.

Comment: You defined a reoute for `get` request when your form sends `post` request.

Comment: I changed it to post :begin_planning, I still dont see x getting printed. Could there be any other issue?

Comment: From the looks of it your route is hitting the wrong controller, can you post the output of `rake routes` please

Comment: @MrShemek the issue isn't after the form submits but with when the view loads to begin with (without the @x variable)

Comment: try changing `get :begin_planning` to `get :begin_planning, to: 'submitted_content#begin_planning'`

Comment: I added the routes.

Comment: @TanmayaNanda how did you define your routes ? the suffix `_index` for the path name and the suffix `_controller`  for the controller name are very... unusual

Comment: @Sovalina I added this line: get 'submitted_content/begin_planning', to: 'submitted_content#begin_planning' to routes. Now my rake routes shows as `submitted_content_begin_planning GET    /submitted_content/begin_planning(.:format)                   submitted_content#begin_planning`

Comment: @Sovalina I am still not able to simply print x.

Comment: @TanmayaNanda, what is in your rails server log?

Comment: If you do not know the cause, it is a short cut to intentionally generate an error. If you add `raise ArgumentError.new ('I am here.')` to `def begin_planning` and you get an error, is not it just that `p` is hidden in style sheets etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be rendering the view without going through the action.

If Rails finds a view file with a name that matches a route, but doesn't find a corresponding action for that route, it will still
render the view.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

So, you successfully render the form in the view, but Rails
doesn't know what `@x` means.

In your routes file, try adding the following outside of any namespaces: 
`get '/begin_planning', to: 'submitted_content#begin_planning'`

Your `rake routes` should include the following:
`begin_planning GET  /begin_planning(.:format)  submitted_content#begin_planning`

And navigate to http://localhost:3000/begin_planning

Or,

if you'd like to namespace, you can add the following to your routes file instead:

```
namespace :submitted_content do
    get :begin_planning
end
```

And your 'rake routes' should include the following:

```
submitted_content_begin_planning GET
/submitted_content/begin_planning(.:format)
submitted_content#begin_planning
```

And navigate to http://localhost:3000/submitted_content/begin_planning